# Are a head and tail pointers enough to make my append method constant time in a linked list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, append, big-o

I am implementing a linked list from scratch on Python. I have already implemented. In particular, I am interested in the different implementations of the append method. Following the instructions on the [book that I am using](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590282574), after implementing `append` as a linear time function, I am now trying to implement it in constant time.

I first I create a `Node` class that will help create my linked list:

```
class Node:
    """
    A node class that is used to implement a linked list object.
    The node contains a data field, aka the item in the node and a
    reference to the next node.
    """
    def __init__(self, init_data):
        self.data = init_data
        self.next = None

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next

    def set_data(self, new_data):
        self.data = new_data

    def set_next(self, new_next):
        self.next= new_next
```

Here is my implementation of the linked list with its different methods:

```
from node_class import Node

class UnorderedList:
    """
    An unordered list class built from a collection of nodes.
    """
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.head == None
    
    def add(self, item):
        temp = Node(item)
        temp.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = temp
        

    def size(self):
        current = self.head
        count = 0
        while current != None:
            count += 1
            current = current.get_next()

        return count

    def search(self, item):
        current = self.head
        found = False
        while current != None and not found:
            if current.get_data() == item:
                found = True
            else:
                current = current.get_next()

        return found


    def remove(self, item):
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        found = False
        while not found:
            if current.get_data() == item:
                found = True
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.get_next()

        if previous == None:
            self.head = current.get_next()
        else:
            previous.set_next(current.get_next())

    def print_list(self):
        current = self.head
        while current != None:
            print(current.data)
            current = current.get_next()

    def append(self, item):
        new_node = Node(item)

##      Append Linear Time O(n)
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = new_node
            return 
            
        current = self.head
        found_last = False
        while not found_last:
            if current.get_next() == None:
                found_last = True
                current.set_next(new_node)
                
            else:
                current = current.get_next()
```

I know my implementation of append is linear time as it has to traverse the length of the list to find the last Node so it can append my new node to it.

The logic I am following to implement my constant time solution is first adding an instane variable named tail so I can point it to the last node (thus bypassing the need to traverse the whole list to find the last node). I am considering the special case where my list might be only 1 item long.

Intuitively, this should work, as like I mentioned I won't need to traverse the whole list to find the last item, I can simply set my tail's next node to the new node that I want to append. My question is, whether there are any instances where this won't work?

I added a modified version of my add method as it is another way of adding nodes and I will need to keep track of the last node too if I want to keep my append method constant time.

```
class UnorderedList:
    """
    An unordered list class built from a collection of nodes.
    """
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
    
    def add(self, item):
        temp = Node(item)
        temp.set_next(self.head)
        if self.head == None:
            self.tail = temp
        self.head = temp
        

    def append(self, item):
        new_node = Node(item)
##      Append Constant Time O(1)

        if self.head == None:
            self.tail = new_node
            self.head = new_node
            return
        else:
            self.tail.set_next(new_node)
            return
```

Comment: If your 1 question is your current title, it's not clear how the body is asking it & your post is missing research & an attempt to answer it & has code that is irrelevant. If you don't know how to argue the complexity then research/ask about that instead. Now it asks for a textbook on complexity, read & apply one & ask where stuck. PS I came here from your meta post your question quality. I'm done now. Good luck.